# Add certain class depending on viewport width in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

Is there any way to apply a specific class only on specific viewport width? (other than using media queries)

For example `<div class="mb-1>Hello world</div>` would apply a `margin-bottom` all the time.

but what if I wanted to apply it only when the view port is larger than `sm`?

I am using Angular, so the solution could use Angular helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Bootstrap classes also have responsive classes.

In your case it would be `mb-sm-1`.

You can find out the responsive classes for all components in the Bootstrap docs.

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation)'s for example the responsive classes for the spacing utilities you asked about.

Comment: That answers my question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you wouldn't want to use `@media` queries for this, I mean, that's what they're there for. But, if you must use an alternative method, you could detect viewport width with JS/TS and `@HostListener` to listen to the resize event, then use `[ngClass]` to apply the class.

Something like:

```
viewportWidth: number;

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    this.viewportWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
}

viewportIsGreaterThan(viewportWidth: number): boolean {
    return this.viewportWidth > viewportWidth;
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'mb-1' : viewportIsGreaterThan(499) }">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Well, the thing is I was using this https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API and they have something like this `<div class="class0" ngClass.xs="class1 class2"></div>` .. I find it weird that bootstrap doesnt have anything like this OOTB.

Comment: Hmm, I've never really looked at that library before, so i'm not 100% sure on it, but looking at their sample app at https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/demo-app/app/docs-layout-responsive/responsiveStyle.demo.ts it would appear they use directives attached to break points, so in your case, it would likely be something like:

`<div [ngClass.sm]="[no-mb]" [ngClass.md]="['mb-1']" [ngClass.lg]="['mb-1']">Hello, World</div>`

Where `no-mb` is a class with `margin-bottom: 0;` ?